# How to get a subset of a RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Spark. If I have a RDD consists of key-value pairs, what is the efficient way to return a subset of this RDD containing the keys that appear more than a certain times in the original RDD?

For example, if my original data RDD is like this:

```
val dataRDD=sc.parallelize(List((1,34),(5,3),(1,64),(3,67),(5,0)),3)
```

I want to get a new RDD, in which the keys appear more than once in dataRDD. The newRDD should contains these tuples: (1,34),(5,3),(1,64),(5,0). How can I get this new RDD? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count keys and filter infrequent:

```scala
val counts = dataRDD.keys.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
val infrequent = counts.filter(_._2 == 1)
```

If number of infrequent values is to large to be handled in memory you can use `PairRDDFunctions.subtractByKey`:

```scala
dataRDD.subtractByKey(infrequent)
```

otherwise a broadcast variable:

```scala
val infrequentKeysBd = sc.broadcast(infrequent.keys.collect.toSet)
dataRDD.filter{ case(k, _) => !infrequentKeysBd.value.contains(k)}
```

If number of frequent keys is very low you can filter frequent keys and use a broadcast variable as above:

```scala
val frequent = counts.filter(_._2 > 1)
val frequentKeysBd  = ??? // As before
dataRDD.filter{case(k, _) => frequentKeysBd.value.contains(k)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much zero323!